# How to disable redundant perl prove output?

Tags: perl, unit-testing

`prove` gives me output like this:

```
$ prove t/HealthScores.t 
t/HealthScores.t .. ok   
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=2,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.04 usr  0.00 sys +  0.16 cusr  0.01 csys =  0.21 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

For me the last two lines are redundant and unnecessary. I'd like to disable their display but can't find a CLI switch for this. E.g., I'd like to only see this:

```
$ prove t/HealthScores.t
t/HealthScores.t .. ok
All tests successful.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, I lose the colored text when post-processing it. I'll follow up with `perlbug`.

Comment: "All tests successful." is made redundant by "Result: PASS", but not the other way around as you claim..

Comment: "Files=1, Tests=2,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.04 usr  0.00 sys +  0.16 cusr  0.01 csys =  0.21 CPU)" is not redundant at all. You may not be interested in that info, but that doesn't make it redundant.

Comment: "No news is good news"

Answer (score 1):

No. These are not output conditionally.

```
if ( $aggregate->all_passed ) {
    $self->_output_success("All tests successful.\n");
}

...

my $files = @$tests;
$self->_output("Files=$files, Tests=$total, $runtime\n");
my $status = $aggregate->get_status;
$self->_output("Result: $status\n");
```

Though there does appear to be a way to silence these and other messages since the above is preceded by

```
return if $self->silent;
```